# How to add a Show More/Show Less UIButton to control UITextView

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitextview

I'm using a UITextView to display some contents. Beneath the textView, I added a UIButton that can control if the TextView will display part or all of its content.

Ideally, when button tapped, the TextView will expand its Height to accommodate the length of the content.

I haven't found a good solution. I wonder if I should use UIlabel instead of textView.

Comment: It is very easy to implement. 

Follow these steps:
1. Create a UITextView with static height and add "Showmore" button at the bottom of textview.
2. On click of uibutton change the height of uitextview. Change the height according to the text in it and then update the frame of button also. Change the Title of butto to "Showless".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this thing working this way:

**1. Add a UITextView and UIButton in Storyboard.**

[image]

**2. If you are using Autolayout Constraints, make an outlet of UITextView height.**

[image]

**3. In ViewController class make outlets as:**

> @IBOutlet var txtView: UITextView!
>
> @IBOutlet var btn_Show: UIButton!
>
> @IBOutlet var textView_HeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

**4. Make a method that will give you height of UITextView according to the text in it.**

> ```
> func getRowHeightFromText(strText : String!) -> CGFloat
> {
>     let textView : UITextView! = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:      self.txtView.frame.origin.x,
>     y: 0, 
>     width: self.txtView.frame.size.width,
>     height: 0))
>     textView.text = strText
>     textView.font = UIFont(name: "Fira Sans", size:  16.0)
>     textView.sizeToFit()
>
>     var txt_frame : CGRect! = CGRect()
>     txt_frame = textView.frame
>
>     var size : CGSize! = CGSize()
>     size = txt_frame.size
>
>     size.height = 50 + txt_frame.size.height
>
>     return size.height
> }
> ```

**5. On Click of Button:**

> ```
>    @IBAction func showMore_Button_Clicked(_ sender: UIButton)
>
>      {
>
>        if sender.tag == 0
>
>          {
>             let height = self.getRowHeightFromText(strText: self.txtView.text)
>
>             self.textView_HeightConstraint.constant = height
>
>             self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
>
>             btn_Show.setTitle("ShowLess", for: .normal)
>
>             sender.tag = 1
>
>         }
>
>         else
>         {
>
>             self.textView_HeightConstraint.constant = 116
>
>             self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
>
>             btn_Show.setTitle("ShowMore", for: .normal)
>
>             sender.tag = 0
>
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

**6. If you are not using AutoLayoutConstraints, just change the Frame(Height) of UITextView on click of UIButton. No need of "`textView_HeightConstraint`"**

```
 @IBAction func showMore_Button_Clicked(_ sender: UIButton)

    {

        if sender.tag == 0

        {

            let height = self.getRowHeightFromText(strText: self.txtView.text)

            self.txtView.frame = CGRect(x: self.txtView.frame.origin.x, y: self.txtView.frame.origin.y, width: self.txtView.frame.size.width, height: height)

            btn_Show.setTitle("ShowLess", for: .normal)

            sender.tag = 1

        }

        else

        {

            self.txtView.frame = CGRect(x: self.txtView.frame.origin.x, y: self.txtView.frame.origin.y, width: self.txtView.frame.size.width, height: 116)

            btn_Show.setTitle("ShowMore", for: .normal)

            sender.tag = 0

        }

    }
```

Comment: This is really nice. THanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome. :) Let me know if any help needed regarding this.