# How to update constraint in tableViewController by tapping showMore/showLess button

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a tableViewController and in the first cell I put a textView with showMore/ShowLess button. like in this answer: [How to add a Show More/Show Less UIButton to control UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107980/how-to-add-a-show-more-show-less-uibutton-to-control-uitextview).
My question is: how can I update constraints when the user click on showMore button and when click on showLess?
I have 2 classe one called: TableViewController and the other is TableViewControllerCell.

```
class TableViewControllerCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var seeMoreButtonO: UIButton!
var heightConstraint:CGFloat = 50 // I don't know how to implement the constraint value

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()


}

func getRowHeightFromText(strText : String!) -> CGFloat
{
    let textView : UITextView! = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: descriptionTextView.frame.origin.x,y: 0,width: descriptionTextView.frame.size.width,height: 0))
    textView.text = strText
    textView.font = UIFont(name: "Fira Sans", size:  16.0)
    textView.sizeToFit()

    var txt_frame : CGRect! = CGRect()
    txt_frame = textView.frame

    var size : CGSize! = CGSize()
    size = txt_frame.size

    size.height = 50 + txt_frame.size.height

    return size.height
}

@IBAction func showMoreButton(_ sender: UIButton) {


    if sender.tag == 0 {

        let height = self.getRowHeightFromText(strText: self.descriptionTextView.text)
        self.heightConstraint = height
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        seeMoreButtonO.setTitle("ShowLess", for: .normal)
        sender.tag = 1
    } else {

        self.heightConstraint = 116
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        seeMoreButtonO.setTitle("ShowMore", for: .normal)
        sender.tag = 0
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

keep your constraint IBOutlet and update value, but in your case if you have uitableview, i would suggest use of tableview own methods, like this

1- when you want to keep cell as show less, set height of cell of some constant say 50, in heightoftablviewcell
2- once tapped on on show more update your cell height, you can keep track of each cell hight for individual cases in model/dic

Answer (score 0):

Create an outlet for the constraint and set your desired value like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var seeMoreConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And in the place you want to update the constraint:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
    seeMoreConstraint.constant = /* Desired value, for example 50.0 */
    self.view.setNeedsLayout() /* This tells the UI to update */
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```